# Exclude artifacts from assemble task

Tags: java, gradle

In order to use results of one project's task in another project I created a consumable configuration in one project and use this configuration in another project. Although this is the origins of the issue, it boils down to the simple java build file with a configuration:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
task createChecksums(type: Task) {
}
configurations {
    release {
        canBeConsumed = true
        canBeResolved = false
    }
}
artifacts {
    release(file("someFile")) {
        builtBy createChecksums
    }
}
```

When I run `gradlew assemble` it also runs `createChecksums` task. It seems to me that the `assemble` task builds all artifacts.

Is there any way to configure configurations in such a way that artifacts are only built when needed by another project which consumes the configuration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filter gradle configuration for specific libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278434/filter-gradle-configuration-for-specific-libraries)

Comment: Not really, this answer is about filtering in the Copy task, mine is about dependecy configurations and artifacts.

Comment: Okay, thanks for checking. I'm not clear what the problem is though. Could you update your question to show what goes wrong? Are there error messages? When you run `./gradlew prepareRelease`, it will log the tasks that are run - can you update your question to include these, and also explain which tasks should or shouldn't run?

Comment: @aSemy I updated the question and removed the multi-project part, although it was what triggered the question in the first place.